# are updated health checks causing App Engine deployment to fail?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

we updated our google app engine health checks from the legacy version to the new version using and now our deployments are failing. Nothing else on the project has changed. We tested the default settings and then extended checks just in case.

This is the error:
`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.`

This is our app.yaml:

```
liveness_check:
   check_interval_sec: 120
   timeout_sec: 40
   failure_threshold: 5
   success_threshold: 5
   initial_delay_sec: 500

readiness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 120
  timeout_sec: 40
  failure_threshold: 5
  success_threshold: 5
  app_start_timeout_sec: 1500
```

Unfortunately, no matter the configuration, both the readiness and liveness checks are throwing 404s.

What could be causing the problem? and how can we debug this?
Is it possible to rollback to the legacy health checks?

Comment: Update: The updated health checks are causing the problem. We just changed our app.yaml to use legacy health checks and we were able to deploy without a hitch.

Comment: How do you go back to using legacy healthchecks? The command `gcloud beta app update --split-health-checks` only goes one way.

Comment: For now (until 2018-09-30) you can roll back to the old healthchecks by running `gcloud app update --no-split-health-checks` and then redeploying. Beware that old healthchecks will be going away at the end of September 2018 though. Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks

Comment: similar issue with new deployment! the option to revert to legacy health checks doesn't exist for new deployments and it seems health checks are a persistent issue - raised it here again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62735687/google-app-engine-deployment-fails-because-of-failing-readiness-check

Answer (score 7):

This is usually caused when the application is still reading from the legacy health check flags and/or deploying the app using `gcloud app deploy` without enabling the updated health checks first. You can check this by:

1- Making sure the legacy `health_check` flag does not exist on your app.yaml.

2- Run `gcloud beta app describe` to see whether `splitHealthChecks` flag is set to true under `featureSettings`.

By default, HTTP requests from updated health checks are not forwarded to your application container. If you want to extend health checks to your application, then specify a path for liveness checks or readiness checks.

You can then enable updated health checks by using `gcloud beta app update --split-health-checks --project [your-project-id]`. See [this public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/65500706) or this article about [Updated Health Checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#updated_health_checks) about for more details.

Comment: What if you have two apps under the same project? I have an `app.yaml` that runs on GAE classic and a `vm.yaml` that runs on flexible. How does `gcloud beta app update` affect those?

Comment: @speedplane just specify the regular, old health checks in your app.yaml. That's what I did to make it work. 

```health_check:
  enable_health_check: True
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  unhealthy_threshold: 2
  healthy_threshold: 2```

Comment: The split-health-checks setting is project-wide. It doesn't apply to App Engine Standard though, only Flexible Environment. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks

Comment: Hi Kenworth, what do you mean by "By default, HTTP requests from updated health checks are not forwarded to your application container. If you want to extend health checks to your application, then specify a path for liveness checks or readiness checks.", how do I "specify a path for liveness checks or readiness checks" ?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I solved this issue by manually increasing memory allocation?

```
resources:
    cpu: 1
    memory_gb: 2
    disk_size_gb: 10
```

Found this solution in a google forum: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Po_-SkC5DOE

Comment: After spending an hours or so playing with health check settings and digging through the log files, this solution worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want to migrate to the default settings for splitted health checks, follow these steps:

1) Remove `health_check`, `liveness_check` and `readiness_check` sections from your app.yaml file

2) Deploy to a newer version, This is important. So, for example, if your current version is `production`, change it to something else like `prod` in the command `gcloud app deploy --version [new-version-name]`

Comment: if above doesn't work, run this command as well `gcloud app update --split-health-checks --project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]`

Comment: Most people will get here because it doesn't work with the default settings